# Regex in Javascript to match routes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to use a regex, to find matching Strings in Javascript.

for instance:

```
/bla/* should match /bla/something
/bla/*/* should match /bla/something/someOhther
/bla/*/*/blub should match /bla/something/someOhther/blub
```

So actually the * are placeholder and can be anything. I didn't find a good way to do this in regex, but I'm pretty sure there's an easy way.. Could you assist?

Comment: Replace `*` with negated character class `[^/]*` (`[^\/]*`) pattern.

Comment: not really clear... what do you want to match exactly ? one regex for all, one regex per case ?

Comment: yeah, I know that, but somehow I was not able to get a working (complete) regex that works in each case :-/

Comment: @M.Be one for all would be incredible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `/` with `\/` and `*` with `.*` and it should match like

```
"/bla/something/someOhther".match(/\/bla\/.*\/.*/)
```

and convert your input regex to actual regex by doing

```
"/bla/*/*".replace(/\*/g, ".*").replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```

**Edit**

To ensure that `.` doesn't match the entire string, then replace `.` with `[^/]`

```
"/bla/something/someOhther".match(/^\/bla\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*/$) ; //will match
```

but this won't match

```
"/bla/something/someOhther/hj".match(/^\/bla\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*/$) ; //will not match due to extra /hj
```

and convert your input regex to actual regex by doing

```
"/bla/*/*".replace(/\*/g, "[^\/]*").replace(/\//g, "\\/");
```

Comment: awesome. one last bit is missing.
now /bla/something/ is also matching. I don't want to match * to / but only if there's a value.

for instance
/bla/blub/ should not match /bla/*/*

Comment: @Christian try the updates, this should handle your scenario as well.